Can I get my DEX on dual wield bonus attack using Nick?

Nick: When you make the extra attack of the Light property, you can make it as part of the Attack action instead of as a Bonus Action. You can make this extra attack only once per turn.

Does this mean I can still add my DEX modifier to the “bonus attack”, now that it is considered part of the Attack action?

No, you still don't get positive ability modifiers to damage
The reduced damage is not because the extra attack is a Bonus Action, it's part of the definition of the extra attack granted by the Light property:

When you take the Attack action on your turn and attack with a Light weapon, you can make one extra attack as a Bonus Action later on the same turn. That extra attack must be made with a different Light weapon, and you don’t add your ability modifier to the extra attack’s damage unless that modifier is negative.

It being the extra attack granted by Light is what makes you not add the modifier, Nick is just changing that same Light-granted extra attack to be part of your main action, not a separate Bonus Action.

I agree it doesn't add to the damage, but do they add DEX modifier to the attack roll?

I think this answer is technically correct, but it might be beneficial to add an overview of how 2-wpn fighting works in 2024. This would be helpful for folks familiar with 2014 as well as new players.

@MindwinRememberMonica: They'd add the Dex modifier to the attack roll no matter what, there's no rule that even comes close to indicating you wouldn't get the attack roll modifier, it's only damage that is ever affected.

@Wyrmwood there's a reason almost all users have access to the "edit" command under answers. I doubt ShadowRanger would take offense if you expanded upon his answer.

@ShadowRanger new edition, new rules. I looked at nothing 2024-ish and make no assumptions.

@MindwinRememberMonica Except, especially in the case of newly released rules, not all who can edit have access....
